# How to insert a word/text in the beginning of each line

Tags: vim

Just want to insert a word or text at the beginning of range of lines, or the entire file. How do it in vim?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The command:

```
:%s/^/foo: /
```

...inserts `foo:` (including a trailing space) at the beginning of each line.

For a range you can use line numbers:

```
:10,20s/^/foo: /
```

...will do it for line 10 to 20.

My preferred way to do it for a range of lines is this: move the cursor to the first line of the range, then enter `ma` to set the marker `a` to the current line. Move to the end of the range and enter

```
:'a,.s/^/foo: /
```

Comment: Another good, more interactive method is to use visual block mode (ctrl-V) to select the first column, then `I` to insert - type what you need, hit escape, and it'll be added to all the lines. This of course works in any column, not just the first, and you can also use `A` to append, or `c` or `d`.

Comment: Err.... Hefromi: why didn't you make this an answer? It's a good one. Or could have been.

Comment: @Jefromi: You should make your comment an answer, ctrl-V is easier to use than `:s`.

Comment: I've seen some colleagues using ctrl-V but the advantage of `:s` is that it works on every vim and every vi.

Comment: :substitute is also much more powerful. BTW, :s can be used with lines visually selected.

Comment: Does `^` mean "beginning of the line"? Also, how would you specify the end of the line? Before coming here I tried typing `:%I#` to insert a hash at the beginning of every line (I figured I was typing `%` (for each line) `I` insert at beginning of line `#`. But vim doesn't read it like that, I guess, which confused me a bit.

Comment: @AlexG `^` does mean "beginning of the line". Just replace it with `$` to get "end of the line". For example, `:%s/$/foo: /`

Answer (score 36):

I've become much more accustomed to use visual blocks for this kind of thing:

- Move to the start of the first line in your range (`gg` for first line, `^` to move to the start)
- `<C-V>`
- Move down to the last line in your range
- `Ifoo<ESC>`

That would insert `foo` at the start of each line.

Comment: this works great for beginnings. any tips for ends? :D

Comment: @Christy visual _block_ selection isn't the right tool for the job if you're working with ends of lines of different lengths. I'd stick to `:%s/^/.../`.